# How can I speed up this for loop? C++

Tags: c++, optimization

The code:

```
int num=999999; //or generally a very big number (like 10^6, etc.)

int sum=0;

for(int i=num; i>=1; i--) sum+=i;
```

**So basically I want to find the sum of the** `num + num-1 + num-2 +...+ 1`, **is there any way to make for loop faster or to get rid of it entirely?**

Comment: why do you think you need to speed this up? Compilers know this pattern, and replace the loop with a constant. (Of course you should do this in your code to be explitic, but performance-wise I expect no difference)

Comment: Be aware that, whichever method you use, the answer (or an intermediate calculation) is likely to overflow an int, leading to undefined behavior.  On most implementations, an int has 32 bits, so the largest value it can represent is a little over two billion.  Your example with num set to 999999 results in almost 500 billion.  If you naively use the equation given in the accepted answer, you'll compute an intermediate value of nearly 1 trillion.  Using `std::int64_t`, `long long`, or `std::ptrdiff_t` will get you much more room.  Using an unsigned integral type will buy you one more bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a math problem.

The loop can be avoided by using a formula for the sum of the integers from 1 up to and including a positive integer n, given as

> sum = n * (n + 1) / 2

Comment: Thank you! But I found that for my code to work there is need to be a little change in it, not n(n-1)/2 but n(n+1)/2, but still tysm.

Comment: there was an edit inverting the sign. it's been fixed.

Comment: @s4g If you want to thank him, you should upvote / mark as resolve :)

Comment: In case of "generally really big numbers", though the formula might cause an overflow of the integer type used (nearly `n^2` as intermediary value). So the loop approach, while slower - manages bigger numbers for the same integer type.

Comment: @BitTickler But a slight variation on the formula will avoid the overflow possibility, simply divide whichever of `n` and `n+1` is even by `2` before multiplying. Really no need for a loop.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer does not have the same overflow behavior as the original code. If you are using 32 bit signed integers and the input is in the range [46341, 65536) the original code will produce the correct result, but the formula given will overflow and give an incorrect result. This may be amended by first casting to a larger data type, or by switching to a different formula, such as the one given below.

```
int s = ((n / 2) * ((n + 1) / 2)) * 2 + n / 2 + (n & 1);
```

While this is significantly more complicated it does resolve the overflow issue and also works for larger data types where you may not have the ability to cast it to an even bigger type to avoid overflow issues.